# What does it mean to say "le pied!" and where does it come from?

Tags: sens, usage, argot

Recently I read the expression "le pied!" in a social network. I searched around and found a translation like "nice / very good / cool". It appears to be very informal language. So my question is in what context would I use this expression? Where does it come from, i.e. why "pied"?

Comment: It seems to be a derivation from « prendre son pied ». Which, according to WikiTionnaire was used by pirates when they shared their treasure with the feet metric system.

Comment: Voir _Prendre son pied_ [ici](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_son_pied) ou [là](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/prendre-son-pied.php)

Comment: @Larme Could be, but then I have even more questions than before ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey):

Très longue entrée à **pied**.

> [...] Dès 1080 dans La Chanson de Roland, **pied** est employé par
>   métonymie pour désigner une unité de mesure. *Un pied de* ... vaut
>   pour une « certaine quantité », d'où l'expression pied de (1648, en
>   parlant d'un fard<sup>1</sup>) et la locution ***faire un pied de nez***...

suivent un certain nombre de locutions contenant le mot **pied**

> Dans la plupart de ces locutions et expressions, le sens de *pied* est
>   d'ailleurs compris à tort avec le sens anatomique ou le sens figuré de
>   « base ». C'est notamment le cas de la locution familière ***prendre
>   son pied*** (1899 en argot ; répandu v. 1968) qui renvoie pourtant au
>   sens de « mesure » par l'intermédiaire de l'acceptation argotique de «
>   part, portion du butin », ***prendre son pied*** (ou son *fade*)
>   signifiait d'abord « prendre sa part du butin » tout comme *en avoir
>   son pied* '1881), qui ne se dit plus, « en avoir sa part, en avoir
>   assez ». De l'argent des voleurs à celui des prostituées, l'expression
>   est devenue synonyme d'«avoir sa part de plaisir amoureux », le mot
>   comportant des connotations érotiques véhiculées par l'idée de «
>   membre » (quand pied est au singulier).

Le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey)  reprend en gros le même historique et ajoute :

> (v. 1968) *Le pied* : le plaisir, *Quel pied, ce film* ! *C'est pas le
>   pied aujourd'hui*, ça ne va pas bien.

Pour ce qui est du contexte, c'est une expression très familière, quasi argotique et ça se dit couramment entre potes mais pas en bonne société ou à son patron.

<sup>1</sup> Fard = fardeau